# change both legend titles in a ggplot with two legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have two legends on my ggplot with two different legend titles (automatically created from `ggplot()`). Now, I want to change this legend titles.  `+ labs(colour = "legend name")` only change the second legend title. How can I change the first one, too?

Sample data:

```
dataset <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1264572000, 1266202800, 1277362800), 
class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = ""), 
x1 = c(-0.00183760994446658, 0.00089738603087497, 0.000423513598318936), 
x2 = c("approach x","approach y","approach z"), 
x3 = c("Type1", "Type1", "Type2")) ,
.Names = c("date", "data","code","type"),
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code to produce the plot:

```
p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=date, y=data)) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(type), color = code)) +
scale_shape_manual(value=c(23,15))
print(p)
```

The legend titles are on default: "factor(type)" and "code":
[image]

Comment: You don't provide sample data, resulting in not reproducible code.  It will be much easier to help you if you provide sample data and code that we can reproduce.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here is an example using the `iris` dataset:

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=Species, colour=Petal.Width)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient() +
    labs(shape="Species label", colour="Petal width label")
```

You specify the labels using `labs()`, with each scale separately specified, i.e. `labs(shape="Species label", colour="Petal width label")`.

[image]

Comment: You can specify the labs in via scale() too ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Species, colour=Petal.Width)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient("Petal width label") +
    scale_shape("Species label")

Comment: Thank you, Its working. I have a further question: I have many entrys in **code** (see my example), so in the plot there are many colors. Now, for example I want color only "approach z" black, and leave the other unchanged (they are colored automatically). For this, the following code doesn´t work: `+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("approach z" = "black"))`

Comment: @pmuench Have a look at the examples in the documentation for `scale_manual` at http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_manual.html

Comment: @Andrie I have, but they replace all of the colors. I want only replace one and leave the other (automatic colored) unchanged.

Comment: That question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075140/in-r-how-do-i-change-the-color-value-of-just-one-value-in-ggplot2s-scale-fill-br/6075772#6075772

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Andrie, is there a way to change the legend text labels in the second legend? I can change the title, but I'd like to change the names of the labels (e.g. setosa and versicolor in your above example)

Answer (score 15):

If I understood your point correctly, you can simply use `+ labs(shape = "shape legend title", colour = "colour legend title")`