# Suppress redraw when calling polygon in R

Tags: r, graphics

I would like to draw 60,000+ non-overlapping triangles (part of an unstructured triangular mesh) on a single plot in R. Currently, it takes 15-20 minutes per plot, which makes it impossible to use this for making animations. For example,

```
n <- 100 #Except replace this with 60,000
x <- matrix(runif(3*n), n)
y <- matrix(runif(3*n), n)
cols <- heat.colors(n)[order(x[,1])]
poly <- function(i) {polygon(x[i,], y[i,], col=cols[i])}
plot(0, xlim=c(min(x),max(x)), ylim=c(min(y),max(y)))
sapply(1:n, poly)
```

Is it possible to suppress polygon() from redrawing after every polygon? I'm guessing that is the most time consuming step, and it's not mentioned in the man page. Alternative suggestions for how to achieve this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but does `dev.hold(100)` then plotting, then `dev.flush(100)` help any? If on Linux, you might change the X11 backend to `"dbcairo"` and see if that speeds things up - you can control the screen refresh rate to some extent. See `?X11`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass several polygons to `polygon`. All you have to do is separate then with `NA`. here's a code:

```
cuts <- function(x)
{
    n <- length(x) %/% 3

    map <- rep(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE), n)

    result <- rep(NA, n*4)

    result[map] <- x

    result
}


set.seed(1234)

n <- 10000
x <- matrix(runif(3*n), n)
y <- matrix(runif(3*n), n)
cols <- heat.colors(n)[order(x[,1])]
plot(0, xlim=c(min(x),max(x)), ylim=c(min(y),max(y)))
polygon(x=cuts(t(x)), y=cuts(t(y)), col=cols)
```

Works fast. I've tested controlling the seed and comparing with the plot generated by your code.

Comment: +1! Good solution. and it is in the base package. I think the time are similar with the grid package.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

here a vectorized solution using `grid.polygon` of the `grid` package. I use the `lattice` just to draw the scene( `xyplot(0~0)` ~ `plot(0)`).

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)
xyplot(0~0, xlim=c(min(x),max(x)), ylim=c(min(y),max(y)),
       panel=function(...)
       {
         grid.polygon(x  = as.vector(t(x)),
                      y  = as.vector(t(y)),
                      id = rep(1:n,each=3),
                      gp=gpar(fill=cols),
                      def='native')         
       })
```

This takes less than 30 seconds in my modest PC to generate the 60000 polygons.