# Efficiency of drawing rectangles on image matrix in R

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix, rectangles

I have the function `drawRect` which will draw a rectangle on a `n x m x 3` matrix (one layer for each color channel).

It takes in 2 main parameters: the rectangle params `c(xleft, xright, ytop, ybottom)` and the image matrix `im`

```
drawRect <- function(rect, im, color=2){
  int = 255
  im[rect[3]:rect[4],rect[1],color] = int
  im[rect[3]:rect[4],rect[2],color] = int
  im[rect[3],rect[1]:rect[2],color] = int
  im[rect[4],rect[1]:rect[2],color] = int
  return(im)
}
```

The function works as its supposed to. However, I am trying to draw ~2000 rectangles on a `3400 x 5200 x 3` image and this is where it becomes EXTREMELY slow.

I have a `2000 x 4` matrix of rectangle parameters which looks something like:

```
#xleft xright ytop ybottom
313    413  143     243
413    513  143     243
513    613  143     243
613    713  143     243
713    813  143     243
811    911  143     243
...
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up?...

*Note* my images are read in using the `readJPEG` function of the `jpeg` package  and are written to a file using the `writeJPEG` function.

---

Edit: I've tried passing in the matrix of rectangle params and using an apply function to avoid multiple calls of the function, but still no significant improvement.

```
drawRect2 <- function(rects, im, color=2, int = 255){

  x=apply(rects, 1, function(rect){
      im[rect[3]:rect[4],rect[1],color] = int
      im[rect[3]:rect[4],rect[2],color] = int
      im[rect[3],rect[1]:rect[2],color] = int
      im[rect[4],rect[1]:rect[2],color] = int
  })

  return(im)
}
```

Comment: Well theres not much to the function really... I tried wrapping it in an apply but that didnt help much. The writing part isn't a concern for me. It writes pretty fast.

Comment: The reason your function is likely quite slow is because modifying the array requires copying it inside your function. So each time you call that function, R is probably creating (at least) one copy of your entire array.

Comment: I've tried wrapping it in an apply function to avoid multiple calls to the function. Still no significant improvement (see edit)

Comment: `apply` won't really ever speed anything up. That's a common myth.

Comment: So what are you suggesting?

Comment: Don't really have one. Either come up with a way to vectorize your function, or do it in C++ with Rcpp, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is a vectorized version of `rect` but you can use `poylygon` which is vectorized . You need just to  add NA between rectangles. This answer is inspired from the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534032/suppress-redraw-when-calling-polygon-in-r/15534699#15534699).

```
cuts <- function(x)
{
  n <- length(x) %/% 4
  map <- rep(c(rep(TRUE,4),FALSE), n)
  result <- rep(NA, n*5)
  result[map] <- x
  result
}


n <- 2000

xbottom <- runif(n)
ybottom <- runif(n)
xtop <- xbottom+runif(n)
ytop <- ybottom+runif(n)

x <- cbind(xbottom,xbottom,xtop,xtop)
y <- cbind(ybottom,ytop,ytop,ybottom)
cols <- heat.colors(n)[order(x[,1])]
plot(0, xlim=c(min(x),max(x)), ylim=c(min(y),max(y)))
polygon(x=cuts(t(x)), y=cuts(t(y)), col=cols)
```

This will creates the 2000 rectangles instantaneously.

[image]