# How to expand colour palette in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi everybody I am making a graphic in ggplot2 but I wish to add different colour to it. One way is to use palette from `RColorBrewer` package. I used a palette from this package but I got this. The code that I used is the next:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
#Graphic
png(filename = "Atotal.png", width = 1050, height = 900)
Atotal=ggplot(Melt.Atotal, aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = Mes)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3") +
  annotate("text", x = ncol(AtotalM) - 1.3, y = finalValA1 + 4000000, 
           label = finalValA1f, size = 5) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,colour="grey20",face="bold"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="grey20",face="bold",hjust=1,vjust=0.8),axis.title.x=element_text(colour="grey20",face="bold"),axis.title.y=element_text(colour="grey20",face="bold"))+xlab('Mes')+ylab('Total')+ ggtitle("Consumo Automotriz (A)")+theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=3, face="bold", color="black",family="F",size=24))
print(Atotal)
dev.off()
```

The result of using `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")` inside this code is the next:

[image]

Where not all values of `Mes` are being considered. My data is `Melt.Atotal` and it has 3 variables `Mes`, `Var2` and `Value`. The code to build  `Melt.Atotal` is the next (I add `dput()` version of my basic matrix):

```
Melt.Atotal <- melt(AtotalMt)
Melt.Atotal<-transform(Melt.Atotal, Var1 = factor(Var1, colnames(AtotalMt)),
                       Var2 = factor(Var2, rownames(AtotalMt)))
names(Melt.Atotal)[1] <- "Mes"
```

The `dput()` version of `AtotalMt` is the next:

```
structure(c(26854799.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25308105.96, 2048291.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23675677.38, 2019295.58, 3043637.6, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22325824.08, 
1977947.76, 2994958.95, 3669634.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20947118.18, 1945806.86, 2870951.11, 3623960.37, 
3641665.16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20106655.89, 
1919815.43, 2827562.38, 3557471.33, 3598447.3, 6780879.37, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18667088.88, 1776866.25, 
2728334.76, 3481461.59, 3537170.97, 6703991.88, 6229245.09, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16845310.67, 1656723.88, 2649675.68, 
3331967.07, 3393759.08, 6514307.07, 6101157.64, 5553163.01, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15930902.54, 1643219.04, 2511944.81, 
3284255.37, 3243600.72, 6392642.61, 5931591.11, 5456712.16, 6372919.9, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14805849.82, 1615497.99, 2485435.88, 
3160371.22, 3220851.12, 6205541.07, 5782747.54, 5289908.54, 6228697.79, 
6755054.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13598279.47, 1543252.95, 
2406932.77, 3079437.34, 3066205.85, 5939178.65, 5418784.54, 5146445.86, 
6057527.35, 6564332.71, 7119008.27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12795858.11, 
1513931.53, 2364512.31, 2968182.7, 2974803.21, 5750644.13, 5209696.29, 
4974437.54, 5824911.96, 6496834.58, 6982259.62, 7585411.87, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11758983.37, 1463851.51, 2257773.94, 2908980.44, 
2842786.2, 5571236.68, 5231547.64, 4843015.16, 5645654.72, 6291395.12, 
6849018.72, 7394553.35, 7258675.63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10777426.87, 
1444585.43, 2205824.51, 2856067.03, 2656671.24, 5387412.76, 4891235.85, 
4788887.82, 5403486.34, 6021463.61, 6669060.68, 7121591.46, 7112320.54, 
7250944.21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10266106.58, 1451698.54, 2040868.4, 
2834443.74, 2607311.71, 5350935.23, 4986150.11, 4700554.49, 5283671.93, 
5995160.44, 6464991.3, 7090338.26, 6962156.01, 7163824.09, 6211543.17, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9282265.15, 1371250.56, 2017270.91, 2722300.36, 2471954.64, 
5130736.05, 4713668.34, 4465135.85, 5168537.36, 5754071.76, 6297559.65, 
6915271.02, 6772197.84, 6959577.9, 6118091.32, 5795989.01, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 8464668.83, 1283914.03, 1845320.7, 2660890.82, 2377866.52, 
4857393.18, 4469951.91, 4290172.82, 4970032.4, 5530336.24, 6077911.67, 
6606098.28, 6476328.51, 6705017.06, 5935609.39, 5640705.86, 4015226.43, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 7918789.87, 1279609.75, 1881248.3, 2587873.16, 2364394.91, 
4906921.98, 4445721.03, 4284628.74, 4946522.49, 5554209.39, 6014383.31, 
6680961.12, 6344399.8, 6655965.34, 5709641.38, 5550978.64, 3964045.05, 
5391952.87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7198508.1, 1208751.41, 1724855.79, 2499547.5, 
2256276.46, 4558960.92, 4221626.91, 4091117.89, 4770936.83, 5236843.82, 
5714312.29, 6328556.64, 6050113.53, 6477665.43, 5525707.17, 5373406.76, 
3873662.43, 5267242.72, 4367910.18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6463505.48, 1118475.47, 1686515.09, 
2358748.13, 2101583, 4368585.08, 4032671.17, 3754992.4, 4554872.52, 
5088464.45, 5416254.09, 5949658.57, 5820410.69, 6123152.54, 5241203.61, 
5117928.97, 3780923.84, 5064923.02, 4319577.61, 4248144.11, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5981522.92, 
1113893.16, 1649654.18, 2258165.09, 1984585.89, 4182216.8, 3876676.8, 
3736577.48, 4361915.64, 4967747.45, 5421522.41, 5744184.46, 5739301.38, 
5990201.18, 5096379.5, 5013509.94, 3661788.44, 4985665.85, 4215411.02, 
4162236.22, 3537103.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5553863.8, 1042559.75, 1566422.05, 2205045.56, 
1924796.63, 4080172.4, 3725283.16, 3542074.94, 4244071.75, 4612471.39, 
5182532.78, 5709173.1, 5525638.03, 5944624.74, 4901061.55, 4891438.46, 
3509531.92, 4841766.87, 4178459.26, 4010745.77, 3481936.55, 3500595.75, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4918517.28, 
964413.4, 1487320.83, 2052062.38, 1854727.08, 3863049.56, 3538505.25, 
3325688.5, 3960168.53, 4422232.88, 4840572.76, 5305625.33, 5228785.95, 
5595390.47, 4697854.89, 4534514.66, 3216124.85, 4666951.83, 3871215.6, 
3831335.12, 3319421.71, 3426985.34, 4049074.18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4589865.7, 954115.22, 1383875.73, 
2006750.82, 1704060.98, 3710278.82, 3440856.49, 3284324.63, 3881579.99, 
4279966.57, 4876374.02, 5216127.78, 5240486.97, 5463726.92, 4599517.2, 
4565728.74, 3369335.09, 4546853.72, 3913112.94, 3717953.98, 3278679.59, 
3373973.71, 4013406.3, 3279868.96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4176804.11, 888990.38, 1333185.64, 1934096.36, 
1675497.76, 3557827.91, 3299389.42, 3079591.31, 3702946.61, 3992278.82, 
4523001.43, 4981117.99, 4975445.91, 5377398.51, 4533561.81, 4382021.43, 
3213712.98, 4381408.86, 3781808.1, 3625319.37, 3204382.69, 3245757.92, 
3951884.98, 3231005.5, 3420974.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3883820.29, 813949.38, 1265350.22, 1841176.88, 
1603582.53, 3405314.93, 3141362.72, 2807968.09, 3492954.57, 3697604.71, 
4308660.02, 4666512.67, 4709968.33, 5017240.81, 4268580.97, 4145817.08, 
3067212.11, 4151094.71, 3655952.66, 3468151.14, 3133063.94, 3107297.63, 
3809850.33, 3162485.62, 3372197.02, 2602310.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3644460.37, 781745.08, 1204720.53, 
1800978.26, 1554501.31, 3201603.18, 2959079.05, 2739545.56, 3374793.64, 
3525695.81, 4291334.59, 4638114.93, 4666374.2, 4892572.95, 4116606.75, 
4112691.46, 3043441.02, 4125176.99, 3623072, 3349178.97, 3084061.59, 
3084271.42, 3774049.41, 3106863.28, 3295038.38, 2544260.71, 2225635.25, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2725532.3, 695385.39, 
1089829.11, 1635866.34, 1441894.1, 2946913.04, 2844256.31, 2690137.46, 
3035217.37, 3334633.77, 4005528.51, 4022237.61, 4214648.75, 4672725.89, 
3983322.49, 3919345.67, 2756902.02, 3934296.19, 3393367.29, 3235404.74, 
2889134.26, 3024263.51, 3568656.75, 2920654.06, 3178506.86, 2507768.27, 
2186791.52, 2853467.41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3049966.84, 
683350.29, 1074527.94, 1664090.14, 1345253.75, 2839637.6, 2651098.47, 
2500948.78, 3040646.89, 3272387, 3923685.61, 4224081.82, 4210472.99, 
4582848.41, 3755426.17, 3782606.32, 2795678.59, 3898307.39, 3434053.44, 
3121821.28, 2921363.22, 2877461.21, 3512748.84, 2945195.1, 3094739.51, 
2418918.61, 2056727.84, 2784556.5, 2830482.27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2798410.64, 639895.71, 1004919.36, 1510655.38, 
1304308.81, 2740725.42, 2558504.6, 2475013.76, 2939349.12, 3178696.36, 
3747969.66, 4000867.51, 4125018.83, 4349776.89, 3632633.64, 3675764.49, 
2687950.7, 3774205.99, 3431224, 3079305.21, 2816046.7, 2859152.69, 
3393940.45, 2877006.74, 3076307.65, 2326266.7, 2057970.61, 2736991.2, 
2776566.7, 2823590.65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2399320.7, 
624816.39, 965440.49, 1456986.54, 1215055.86, 2553035.48, 2435169.62, 
2332822.03, 2787520.88, 2956835.71, 3408436.53, 3793385.58, 3725354.01, 
4083495.32, 3402962.8, 3315638.6, 2431920.15, 3438929.71, 3132830.19, 
2904787.73, 2662365.19, 2753083.53, 3258576.92, 2806899.51, 2885600.76, 
2215268.28, 1950059.9, 2607609.51, 2699206.83, 2765967.81, 3006568.05, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2201458.94, 571519.44, 843925.91, 
1371876.38, 1178678.1, 2443914.2, 2318665.11, 2252903.7, 2617795.14, 
2859138.88, 3304349.3, 3686591.89, 3674731.78, 3966378.3, 3378997.7, 
3214415.84, 2405071.88, 3366308.49, 2990342.49, 2736475.12, 2607168.86, 
2706348.96, 3213557.76, 2599903.38, 2824306.46, 2164763.75, 1937899.61, 
2579777.7, 2626362.72, 2721182.87, 2931342.61, 2615730, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1959992.56, 509529.58, 799675.48, 1242389.68, 
1141241.83, 2260667.56, 2179604.89, 2159947.31, 2489487.53, 2626465.58, 
3155508.33, 3557859.64, 3464663.89, 3773518.5, 3198567.51, 3252935.25, 
2278042.82, 3273402.14, 2865815.76, 2602186.5, 2577796.07, 2571460.82, 
3175856.78, 2578702.16, 2776048.48, 2096759.57, 1877479.59, 2468371.84, 
2524149.35, 2661768.7, 2882642.88, 2569279.36, 2833299.1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1729244.67, 462014.66, 727394.64, 1180017.89, 
1095320.94, 2183552.82, 2109743.44, 2086989.93, 2345316.13, 2626975.96, 
3068532.68, 3411689.2, 3319895.42, 3722715.8, 3172978.81, 3109894.93, 
2209191.15, 3158834.79, 2838699.9, 2480821.5, 2493415.44, 2528070.2, 
3080337.25, 2481988.35, 2707671.27, 2046364.76, 1873253.27, 2341346.09, 
2442022.48, 2530517.69, 2782013.06, 2511303.35, 2745913.92, 3438797.32, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1549849.2, 458322.22, 718616.27, 1109753.32, 
1017724.67, 2026358.46, 1962226.89, 1997402.05, 2263479.22, 2440781.13, 
2849171.92, 3252589, 3137856.24, 3564965.12, 2984359.05, 2852952.11, 
2112507.39, 2954769.13, 2630636.16, 2380388.06, 2318520.61, 2427464.59, 
2995370, 2412997.64, 2689632.82, 1942677.02, 1834021.04, 2247508.4, 
2369731.57, 2462409.59, 2718120.89, 2430538.52, 2688636.78, 3392755, 
3224926.48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1348175.64, 430661.74, 674424.77, 
1083233.98, 922799.04, 1947889.63, 1865960.21, 1859749.01, 2189887.93, 
2317208.97, 2677149.96, 3058651.31, 3102056.06, 3350904.08, 2871884.58, 
2714588.23, 2030941.81, 2886763.56, 2545676.4, 2203422.72, 2218635.41, 
2336157.9, 2890812.15, 2363224.45, 2585735.04, 1870415.1, 1772222.84, 
2192869.99, 2325864.39, 2430416.64, 2665751.01, 2363822.67, 2584946, 
3338650.08, 3183330.22, 2794029.57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1134174.58, 394195.69, 
627591.36, 986996.97, 905094.24, 1869262.62, 1777335.43, 1831133.54, 
1998551.54, 2130413.1, 2530188.25, 2900885.28, 2989396.31, 3261043.88, 
2817926.06, 2585234.28, 1834641.19, 2692959.95, 2496464.5, 2147759.85, 
2192197.19, 2254492.51, 2801209.29, 2225989.08, 2401570.87, 1786064.52, 
1728411.08, 2117010.38, 2282669.14, 2302139, 2535140.61, 2300978.22, 
2509151.42, 3222196.24, 3102535.64, 2728099.89, 3003458.16, 0, 
0, 0, 1001562.98, 376913.78, 579999.58, 942360.65, 837596.21, 
1777996.71, 1690021.16, 1747746.57, 2052779.77, 2088799.47, 2424260.53, 
2778369.19, 2857931.91, 3142942.88, 2635443.64, 2547750.85, 1822496.3, 
2637954.65, 2452785.43, 2025615.08, 2109856.44, 2262505.43, 2715446.67, 
2172158.39, 2366269.14, 1735742.65, 1662893.95, 2038204.81, 2191816.57, 
2240601.75, 2468849.08, 2234805.75, 2423405.74, 3168668.95, 3035690.96, 
2636414.45, 2919034.44, 2486931.57, 0, 0, 874341.22, 360782.57, 
519507.21, 870288.09, 786998.61, 1663642.58, 1550763.45, 1669917.52, 
1945941.78, 1970075.62, 2329146.26, 2585321.62, 2656298.81, 3029946.39, 
2490842.99, 2435587.25, 1739728.8, 2580447.13, 2258039.32, 1937348.09, 
2013383.14, 2146847.21, 2651523.71, 2053389.25, 2223539.76, 1658829.44, 
1577862.53, 1958701.51, 2122630.01, 2237987.33, 2447107.3, 2145457.33, 
2367896.01, 3090013.67, 2979750.06, 2546079.35, 2850658.25, 2447687.12, 
2515076.46, 0, 727314.1, 342974.57, 488469.13, 783815.37, 723097.48, 
1571210.47, 1459534.22, 1500041.34, 1810510.32, 1871554.2, 2124891.18, 
2465003.74, 2589953.19, 2908070.17, 2328456.61, 2374480.31, 1611237.61, 
2423377.37, 2160764.18, 1819919.89, 1945118.58, 2044143.09, 2478541.13, 
1995214.4, 2107312.32, 1617642.92, 1539948.97, 1915128.43, 2013819.45, 
2106946.21, 2366282.4, 2048390.08, 2320985.47, 2933079.27, 2923955.09, 
2496980.3, 2786647.48, 2380798.87, 2479884.64, 2674568.38), .Dim = c(40L, 
40L), .Dimnames = list(c("jul 10", "ago 10", "sep 10", "oct 10", 
"nov 10", "dic 10", "ene 11", "feb 11", "mar 11", "abr 11", "may 11", 
"jun 11", "jul 11", "ago 11", "sep 11", "oct 11", "nov 11", "dic 11", 
"ene 12", "feb 12", "mar 12", "abr 12", "may 12", "jun 12", "jul 12", 
"ago 12", "sep 12", "oct 12", "nov 12", "dic 12", "ene 13", "feb 13", 
"mar 13", "abr 13", "may 13", "jun 13", "jul 13", "ago 13", "sep 13", 
"oct 13"), c("jul 10", "ago 10", "sep 10", "oct 10", "nov 10", 
"dic 10", "ene 11", "feb 11", "mar 11", "abr 11", "may 11", "jun 11", 
"jul 11", "ago 11", "sep 11", "oct 11", "nov 11", "dic 11", "ene 12", 
"feb 12", "mar 12", "abr 12", "may 12", "jun 12", "jul 12", "ago 12", 
"sep 12", "oct 12", "nov 12", "dic 12", "ene 13", "feb 13", "mar 13", 
"abr 13", "may 13", "jun 13", "jul 13", "ago 13", "sep 13", "oct 13"
)))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set3 has 12 distinct colors (see `?RColorBrewer`). If you want more, you need to interpolate:

```
library(grid) # for unit()
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Set3"))
myPal <- cols(length(unique(Melt.Atotal$Mes)))
Atotal <- ggplot(Melt.Atotal, aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = Mes)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = myPal) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=8),
        legend.key.height=unit(.1, "cm"))
Atotal
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lukeA that is I was looking for only a little question do you know if I can use a palette only with primary colours in ggplot2!

Comment: I guess there is no palette with that many distinct colors. Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563711/r-color-palettes-for-many-data-classes

Comment: Or did you just mean a more RGB'ish palette like `myPal <- rainbow(length(unique(Melt.Atotal$Mes)))`?

Comment: In `scale_fill_gradient2` you can set `low`, `mid` and `high`, using RGB colour space.

Comment: Dear @Henrik where can I find an example of `scale_fill_gradient2` to adapt to my graph I am very new with this topic.

Comment: As ususal in R, you can just type `?scale_fill_gradient2`. However, you find help texts for all `ggplot` functions [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) as well, with output of all the code in the help texts - very convenient to scroll through to find something that looks similar to your own setting.

Comment: [**This**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) is a nice tutorial for `ggplot`, with a section about [**colours**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/).