# How to expand color palette in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, data-visualization

I use `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")` in ggplot2, however since I have more than 12 categorical variables there is an error:

```
Warning in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal) :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Paired is 12
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

So what is an another color palette with> I want to avoid using `continuous scale`

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938729/how-to-expand-colour-palette-in-ggplot2

Comment: 1) don't visualise more than say 8 discrete variables 2) check the linked threads. Also a package like [paletteer](https://cran.r-project.org/package=paletteer) is really good if you want to get an idea of available color palettes for R.