ggplot - highlight a single data set out of many using unique formating Format only a single dataset out of several
There are similar questions on the exchange but I do not think they apply to what I am trying to do here.
I have a point and line plot that has eight datasets. I would like to highlight just one and let the SW autocolor the rest. This is important as I may have instances where I have many more than eight. I do not want to have to manually set colors and just set the one I want to a color and style I specifcy. Is there a quick way to accomplish that?
In the picture below I would like to make CR5 black and dashed as an example.

data = data.frame(A = c("CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7"
)
                         ,TIME = c(0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18
),
VAL = c(0,0.2062,0.3171,0.4032,0.5071,0.5931,0.7325,0.8381,1.0332,1.0945,1.0958,1.0958,1.0893,0,0.1192,0.1822,0.2314,0.2969,0.3583,0.4605,0.5571,0.7956,0.9577,1.0322,1.042,1.0413,0,0.1934,0.3049,0.3936,0.4999,0.5915,0.7453,0.8774,1.0571,1.0694,1.0657,1.0627,1.0658,0,0.0954,0.1427,0.1846,0.2418,0.2972,0.4113,0.5353,0.8212,0.9717,1.0038,1.0002,1.004,0,0.1095,0.1491,0.1875,0.2372,0.278,0.3608,0.4382,0.6466,0.807,0.8972,0.9325,0.9476,0,0.1025,0.1499,0.1884,0.239,0.2848,0.3689,0.4538,0.6884,0.8525,0.947,0.9714,0.9743,0,0.1213,0.1741,0.2158,0.2758,0.3251,0.4297,0.5286,0.785,0.9463,1.0264,1.044,1.0541
))


ggplot (data) +
  geom_point( aes(x = TIME, y = VAL, group = A, color = A )) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = TIME, y = VAL, group = A, color = A )) +
  theme_classic()




it would help to have a reproducible example. in the meanwhile, you can have a look at this link

@gabt updated question with code that produces the plot. I looked at your link but that approach won't help because of the bunching of the data. Is there a more sophisticated way of plucking out a dataset to manipulate?

Does something like this help?
#packages
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(RColorBrewer)

#create a data.table of desired shapes and colors
plot_layout <- data.table(Species = unique(iris$Species))
plot_layout[, col := brewer.pal(n = nrow(plot_layout), name = 'Set2')] #see RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()
plot_layout[, linetype := "solid"]

#adjust for the one factor you want to highlight
plot_layout[Species == "setosa", col := "black"]
plot_layout[Species == "setosa", linetype := "dashed"]

#create individual vectors
col_vector <- plot_layout$col
names(col_vector) <- plot_layout$Species

linetype_vector <- plot_layout$linetype
names(linetype_vector) <- plot_layout$Species

#visualise
ggplot(iris,aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, col = Species, linetype = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = col_vector) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = linetype_vector)



There is probably a shorter solution. Also, check which color palette fits best for you depending on the amount of unique groups you have. The Set2 palette of RColorBrewer, for example, contains 8 unique colors.

This would work! I gave you a point but I will leave it open to see if there is a more concise way to do it.

@marrvd Quick question is there a way to extend your solution to more colors seems like I am limited to < 12

Instead of using RColorBrewer::brewer.pal() to create a vector of colors, you can use other packages, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563711/r-color-palettes-for-many-data-classes and sample from those palettes

there is a solution using gghighlight which requires creating another column in the data dataframe and then plotting:
# load libs
library("ggplot2")
library("gghighlight")

# create data frame
data <- data.frame(A = c("CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR1","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR2","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","CR3","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","Target","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR5","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR6","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7","CR7") ,TIME = c(0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.5,2,3,4,7,10,13,16,18), VAL = c(0,0.2062,0.3171,0.4032,0.5071,0.5931,0.7325,0.8381,1.0332,1.0945,1.0958,1.0958,1.0893,0,0.1192,0.1822,0.2314,0.2969,0.3583,0.4605,0.5571,0.7956,0.9577,1.0322,1.042,1.0413,0,0.1934,0.3049,0.3936,0.4999,0.5915,0.7453,0.8774,1.0571,1.0694,1.0657,1.0627,1.0658,0,0.0954,0.1427,0.1846,0.2418,0.2972,0.4113,0.5353,0.8212,0.9717,1.0038,1.0002,1.004,0,0.1095,0.1491,0.1875,0.2372,0.278,0.3608,0.4382,0.6466,0.807,0.8972,0.9325,0.9476,0,0.1025,0.1499,0.1884,0.239,0.2848,0.3689,0.4538,0.6884,0.8525,0.947,0.9714,0.9743,0,0.1213,0.1741,0.2158,0.2758,0.3251,0.4297,0.5286,0.785,0.9463,1.0264,1.044,1.0541))

# either use the A column for highlighting
ggplot (data,  aes(x=TIME, y=VAL, color=A)) +
    geom_point() +
    # this is where you specify how you want the highlighted line to be
    geom_line(linewidth=1.5, color='cornflowerblue') +
    gghighlight(A == "CR1") +
    theme_classic()

# or add a column for the highlighting for a
# group that should be highlighted
data$highlight <- ifelse(data$A=="CR1", 1, 0)

# then use this new col for highlighting
ggplot (data,  aes(x=TIME, y=VAL, color=A)) +
    geom_point() +
    # this is where you specify how you want the highlighted line to be
    geom_line(linewidth=1.5, color='cornflowerblue') +
    gghighlight(highlight == 1) +
    theme_classic()

however, this method returns a warning and i think it is because highlight is not called within the ggplot's aes but i am not sure. worth giving it a shot.

This is close, is there a way to specify the color and style of the highlighted data. I see I can control what does not make it but not what is selected.

@TheCodeNovice, i added the further mods, to the highlighted data. if you need to dig deeper, have a look at the gghighlight official page.
i still don't know why the warning shows up. if i find an explanation i will post.
