Increasing the number of colors in ggplot
I have this R code that simulates the Degroot model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeGroot_learning) in R about network communication:
I initialized the simulation here:
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(123)

simulate_degroot <- function(n_agents, n_iterations, initial_opinions = NULL) {
  # Initialize opinions
  if (is.null(initial_opinions)) {
    opinions <- matrix(runif(n_agents), nrow = n_agents, ncol = 1)
  } else {
    opinions <- matrix(initial_opinions, nrow = n_agents, ncol = 1)
  }
  
  influence_matrix <- matrix(runif(n_agents^2), nrow = n_agents, ncol = n_agents)
  influence_matrix <- influence_matrix / rowSums(influence_matrix)

From here, I ran the simulation for 20 individuals:
  for (i in 1:n_iterations) {
    opinions <- cbind(opinions, influence_matrix %*% opinions[, i])
  }
  
  return(opinions)
}

n_agents <- 10
n_iterations <- 20

results <- simulate_degroot(n_agents, n_iterations)

df <- melt(results)
colnames(df) <- c("Agent", "Iteration", "Opinion")

From here I tried to visualize the results:
ggplot(df, aes(x = Iteration, y = Opinion, color = factor(Agent))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "DeGroot Model Simulation",
       x = "Iteration",
       y = "Opinion",
       color = "Agent") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")

print(last_plot())


But I get this error:
Warning messages:
1: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal) :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set1 is 9
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

2: Removed 21 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (`geom_line()`). 
3: Removed 21 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (`geom_point()`). 

Is this a hard limit in R for colors?

No, it is just a limit of the color palette you are using. The Set1 palette you specified has 9 colors.

Some prior questions have been asked here related to using more colors, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9563711/6851825.  In general, it's hard in most contexts for people to reliably distinguish more than about a dozen colors -- 20 is probably pushing it if it's important to connect each color with an entry in the legend.
