# problems with ggplot scale, color and linetype parameters

Tags: r

This is my very first post here, hope I can make myself clear! I am trying to accomplish a very subtle change to my ggplot. I am plotting crosshairs centered on (x,y) with SD showing as errorbars, but the complication i have is with the scale and line types. 
I have a dataframe (z) where each row is a aggregate over many rows. Each row will be plotted in the ggplot as a crosshair with its own color, however, some rows of the dataframe should be plotted as normal lines, and others should be plotted in dashed lines. Two columns groupnum and groupttl have numeric values for colors and labels respectively that should be shown in the scale, in addition to colors, i also want to show linetype in the scale bar. But I am not able to figure this out yet!

Here is what my code is doing:

```
chp <- ggplot(data=z,aes(x=x,y=y,colour = group,group = group,linetype=factor(othr))) + 
    theme_bw() + #remove background
    xlab(m1) +
    ylab(m2) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - ySD, ymax = y + ySD, linetype = factor(othr))) + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = x - xSD, xmax = x + xSD, linetype = factor(othr))) +
    guides(linetype=FALSE) + #remove the legend added by linetype
    scale_colour_manual(name=hierarchyname, values=factor(unique(groupnum))) + #add colors manually
    scale_linetype_manual(values = factor(unique(othr)))
```

Note: othr has only two values (1,2) i want to show only two types of lines--normal and dashed.

the closest match i found is this: [Passing variable with line types to ggplot linetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714564/passing-variable-with-line-types-to-ggplot-linetype)

where they say The trick is to use use line_type = geography in conjunction with scale_linetype_manual(values = lty). But in my case, the difference is i don't want each line to have its own linetype, I need only two.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on this. Please let me know if you need more info. 
Thanks 
SP

---

Ok. Thanks for suggestions. Here is my dataframe

```
"groupnum","group","N","x","y","xSE","ySE","xSD","ySD","othr"
"1",1,"a1",874,9.31080482242276,3.78151559519843,0.000919599013717256,0.0010731700399164,0.803729537988882,0.93795061488693,1
"2",2,"a2",323,9.32858454311781,3.85117814673799,0.00434633223522011,0.00262887468315802,1.4038653119761,0.84912652266004,1
"3",3,"a3",401,8.65698443874862,3.61961141000158,0.00320566652230181,0.0024382624307443,1.28547227544303,0.977743234728466,1
"4",4,"a4",364,8.02722008290545,4.03272290234161,0.00664827121575061,0.00285893561941909,2.41997072253322,1.04065256546855,1
"5",5,"a5",2117,9.38192555351799,3.39287371184691,0.000317738758329197,0.000433382027761261,0.672652951382911,0.917469752770589,1
"6",6,"a6",347,9.2600568761331,3.34027019277033,0.00105036291416114,0.0024058297735207,0.364475931213916,0.834822931411683,1
"7",7,"a7",782,9.26685442279479,3.32913948807558,0.000672770018741615,0.00103475341970955,0.526106154655943,0.809177174212869,1
"8",9,"a8",335,9.33774697202318,3.83086473063289,0.0022406672509349,0.0033135194052142,0.750623529063193,1.11002900074676,1
"9",10,"a9",588,9.2362799520667,3.79905936514298,0.000648139660555769,0.00112763352751969,0.381106120406792,0.663048514181577,1
"10",8,"b1",631,9.39770259697672,3.49584647787853,0.00147287975375933,0.00176346535893738,0.929387124622137,1.11274664148949,2
```

which can be read using the command

```
read.table(file = "zp.txt",sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Another requirement is: I would like to use

```
scale_colour_hue(name=hierarchyname, # Legend label, use darker colors
             breaks=unique(group),
             labels=unique(group),#add the legend for all groups
             l=50,       # Use darker colors, lightness=50
             c=100)        #chroma (intensity of color)
```

instead of scale_colour_manual due to better colors, however, this is a secondary problem, first i want the scale to be fixed!

ok was able to edit it too!
Thanks
SP

Comment: I've edited your post to get your example code to show up nicely: Stack Overflow doesn't use HTML tags for formatting, take a look at these formatting tips for next time: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please make an [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Currently you have a reasonable word description of the problem but your code is incomplete, and it would be far easier to have a small reproducible data set to use.

Comment: thank you for editing my question. How did you add the line break between the two questions?

Comment: I've had a look at your data. The remaining problems are: `m1` and `m2` do not exist, neither does `hierarchyname`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without your dataframe `z` to check it's impossible to know, but I think this will work if you change:

```
 scale_linetype_manual(values = factor(unique(othr))
```

to

```
 scale_linetype_manual(values =c(1,2))
```

---

**EDIT**

The following seems to make what you want:

```
chp <- ggplot(data=z,aes(x=x,y=y,colour = group, linetype=as.factor(othr))) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - ySD, ymax = y + ySD)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = x - xSD, xmax = x + xSD)) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(linetype=FALSE)
chp
```

[image]

---

Without `guides(linetype=FALSE)`:
[image]

---

**Manual Solution**

This will let you specify the linetype for the colour scale legend.

```
guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=c(2,rep(1,times=9)))))
```

The `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend()` allows you to adjust legend characteristics in a list. So `linetype` is specified as a 2 and nine ones (dashed is `linetype=2`, solid is `linetype = 1`). This is what I mean by manual.

[image]

Comment: I am kind of out of ideas to fix this issue! does any of you has some ideas?

Comment: in the scale also i want the dotted line to be shown not just in the plot. Also i don't want the grey box around the scale.

Comment: Do you mean legend? Then you need to remove `guides(linetype=FALSE)`. You can't combine the two legends, because they are mapped to difference aesthetics. To make the sorts of changes you want to the legend, you need to read about `theme()` http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html

Comment: I want only single legend showing the dotted line in the legend corresponding to the crosshair. Is there any other way that i can do this!? Also, i want the colors more brighter. Thanks for pointing to the theme, I will look into it.

Comment: You would need to do it manually, but it doesn't make a lot of sense, because colour has a particular meaning, and linetype has a particular meaning. Combining them will only confuse your plot. Bear in mind that stackoverflow is for assistance with programming questions, not getting people to make your plot for you. Please consider accepting/voting for answers - it will encourage people to assist you.

Comment: alexwhan- thnx for your answers! But i have spent a lot of time doing my research before i posted this query here! i sensed that i was hitting a road block so i thought it's time to ask some specific questions. Regarding the plot, I think it is quite reasonable to try to plot two types of data (like from two different data frames) on the same plot with it's own group colors! My R experience is pretty recent, so i want to make sure i try different possibilities...

Comment: Sure - I don't want to be harsh, but in this case I think the distinction between linetype and colour is essential to be maintained - that's why `ggplot` has been written to maintain that. If you're certain you want to do something different, then you'll need to do it all manually. All the best.

Comment: May i ask what you mean by changing manually? you mean outside R?

Comment: I mean specifying each element in the legend manually, in ggplot. See my edit.

Comment: Can i choose the specific color in the legend e.g., for b1 and a9 to have line type = 2!? Also, this is very useful to me, I would like to give you more points for this. thnx!

Comment: ok i figured that i can change the desired line using the position something like this:  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=c(rep(1,times=4),rep(2,times=2),rep(1,times=4))))). But i want to thicken the line width in the legend, it is barely visible. what can i use to increase that? I tired lwd=2, but didn't worl!?