# Default linetypes in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling here to figure out the default linetypes used in ggplot2. I have a dataframe as follows:

```
test <- structure(list(time = c(151.04167175293, 151.125015258789, 151.20832824707, 
151.29167175293, 151.375030517578, 151.45832824707, 151.54167175293, 
151.625015258789, 151.70832824707, 151.79167175293, 151.875030517578, 
151.95832824707, 151.08332824707, 151.166687011719, 151.250030517578, 
151.333343505859, 151.41667175293, 151.5, 151.58332824707, 151.666687011719, 
151.750030517578, 151.833343505859, 151.91667175293, 151.04167175293, 
151.125015258789, 151.20832824707, 151.29167175293, 151.375030517578, 
151.45832824707, 151.54167175293, 151.625015258789, 151.70832824707, 
151.79167175293, 151.875030517578, 151.95832824707, 151.08332824707, 
151.166687011719, 151.250030517578, 151.333343505859, 151.41667175293, 
151.5, 151.58332824707, 151.666687011719, 151.750030517578, 151.833343505859, 
151.91667175293, 151.04167175293, 151.125015258789, 151.20832824707, 
151.29167175293, 151.375030517578, 151.45832824707, 151.54167175293, 
151.625015258789, 151.70832824707, 151.79167175293, 151.875030517578, 
151.95832824707, 151.08332824707, 151.166687011719, 151.250030517578, 
151.333343505859, 151.41667175293, 151.5, 151.58332824707, 151.666687011719, 
151.750030517578, 151.833343505859, 151.91667175293, 151.04167175293, 
151.125015258789, 151.20832824707, 151.29167175293, 151.375030517578, 
151.45832824707, 151.54167175293, 151.625015258789, 151.70832824707, 
151.79167175293, 151.875030517578, 151.95832824707, 151.08332824707, 
151.166687011719, 151.250030517578, 151.333343505859, 151.41667175293, 
151.5, 151.58332824707, 151.666687011719, 151.750030517578, 151.833343505859, 
151.91667175293), value = c(0, 0, 5.61033323376278e-29, 1.54657131948427e-17, 
9.66035151178657e-12, 5.10066877623672e-09, 5.13016118475207e-08, 
5.63439357392781e-08, 2.30620536001425e-08, 9.08235708863003e-09, 
8.37633162831253e-09, 1.55146210545354e-07, 0, 0, 2.25358956126054e-21, 
2.08607626615495e-13, 1.98955163455139e-09, 9.66092130738616e-08, 
1.91719223607834e-07, 1.09957049687637e-07, 3.104455004177e-08, 
1.31108741641128e-08, 6.10190298289126e-08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.2789574202628e-30, 
6.73093043024932e-24, 7.93898871359986e-21, 1.51219769988266e-19, 
3.67432930162413e-19, 7.19692007469365e-19, 3.20756611951269e-18, 
4.69377782154479e-17, 0, 0, 0, 5.28026380068047e-35, 6.81666051928849e-28, 
2.74272295486945e-23, 3.82383180911782e-21, 1.74006456826736e-20, 
4.48768165153377e-20, 1.60533888309098e-19, 1.53676095741939e-18, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.71725244784488e-30, 1.04201812373392e-23, 
2.36111112593732e-21, 5.04498618818828e-20, 1.39487078953905e-19, 
9.53610723085965e-19, 2.04732743716978e-17, 2.28480170675856e-15, 
0, 0, 0, 1.1415638533226e-32, 3.46081290989027e-27, 5.11190859597535e-23, 
2.60199456175554e-21, 8.88056339654886e-21, 2.0802860544737e-20, 
3.12119181655233e-19, 3.69406751642014e-17), id = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), dis = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("50", 
"100", "250", "50(nothing)"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = c("time", 
"value", "id", "dis"), row.names = c("1", "3", "5", "7", "9", 
"11", "13", "15", "17", "19", "21", "23", "722", "724", "726", 
"728", "730", "732", "734", "736", "738", "740", "742", "4321", 
"4323", "4325", "4327", "4329", "4331", "4333", "4335", "4337", 
"4339", "4341", "4343", "5042", "5044", "5046", "5048", "5050", 
"5052", "5054", "5056", "5058", "5060", "5062", "8641", "8643", 
"8645", "8647", "8649", "8651", "8653", "8655", "8657", "8659", 
"8661", "8663", "9362", "9364", "9366", "9368", "9370", "9372", 
"9374", "9376", "9378", "9380", "9382", "12", "32", "52", "72", 
"92", "112", "132", "152", "172", "192", "212", "232", "7221", 
"7241", "7261", "7281", "7301", "7321", "7341", "7361", "7381", 
"7401", "7421"), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, I plot the above dataframe as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test)+
  geom_line(aes(time,value,linetype=dis))+
  facet_wrap(~id,ncol=2)+theme_bw()+
  ylab("concentration ")+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(151,181),ylim=c(-0.15,0.75))+ labs(linetype="")+
  theme(panel.margin = unit(1, "lines"))+ xlab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(151,181),breaks=seq(151,181,5))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.15,1.75),breaks=seq(-0.15,1.75,0.15))+
  theme(legend.position="top",legend.key =element_blank())
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

What I am trying to know is by default what linetypes are used ? Because when I try to use `scale_linetype_manual("", values=c(1,2,3,4))` then it doesn't produce the same `linetypes` as above.

The figure obtained by specifying linetype above is

[image]

Would someone clarify this issue ? Is it possible to achieve the same effect by specifying the linetype ? The reason I am trying to do this is before I had use default and now I need to change one linetype.

I tried with several `linetypes` but cannot figure out what `linetypes` are used when we don't manually specify linetype. Thanks

I don't have data for dis = "100" and "250" over here but should be able to have the same linetype.

**EDIT**

The link to full dataset is as follows: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/dputtest.rda

Comment: The dataset you posted has time in (151,152), so the plots are basically empty.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714564/passing-variable-with-line-types-to-ggplot-linetype) for how to make `scale_linetype_manual(...)` work for you.

Comment: @jlhoward I have added link to the full dataset. We need to just use the command : `test <- read.table("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/dputtest.rda")`

Comment: Very helpful. Have posted response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way to figure out the default `linetypes`, in which order they are used by `ggplot`, and their names.

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = rep(20:1, each = 2), grp = factor(rep(1:20, each = 2)))
df

# plot
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0.95, label = grp)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
p
```

[image]

Apparently, there are 13 default linetypes in `ggplot`. If you look at data in the plot object, you find the corresponding 'names' of the different `linetype`s.

```
g <- ggplot_build(p)
g$data[[1]]

   linetype x  y PANEL group
1     solid 1  1     1     1
2     solid 2  1     1     1
3        22 1  2     1     2
4        22 2  2     1     2
5        42 1  3     1     3
6        42 2  3     1     3
7        44 1  4     1     4
8        44 2  4     1     4
9        13 1  5     1     5
10       13 2  5     1     5
11     1343 1  6     1     6
12     1343 2  6     1     6
13       73 1  7     1     7
14       73 2  7     1     7
15     2262 1  8     1     8
16     2262 2  8     1     8
17 12223242 1  9     1     9
18 12223242 2  9     1     9
19     F282 1 10     1    10
20     F282 2 10     1    10
21 F4448444 1 11     1    11
22 F4448444 2 11     1    11
23 224282F2 1 12     1    12
24 224282F2 2 12     1    12
25       F1 1 13     1    13
26       F1 2 13     1    13
27    blank 1 14     1    14
28    blank 2 14     1    14
...more blanks
39    blank 1 20     1    20
40    blank 2 20     1    20
```

See `?aes_linetype_size_shape` for how to interpret the 'numerical names' and how `linetype` can be specified using "either an integer, a name, or with a string of an even number (up to eight) of characters". A similar description can also be found in `?par`: `lty` and "Line Type Specification"); "The five standard dash-dot line types (`lty = 2:6`) correspond to `c("44", "13", "1343", "73", "2262")`.

Comment: +1 for showing the detailed. Can I assign different linewidths to different linetypes ?

Comment: Yes. In my example, just as `linetype` is mapped to 'grp', you could also map line width (`size`) to 'grp': `geom_line(aes(size = grp))`

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714564/passing-variable-with-line-types-to-ggplot-linetype), to get `scale_linetype_manual(...)` to do what you want, you have to set `values=...` to a *named vector*, as follows:

```
test <- read.table("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/dputtest.rda")

lt.names <- c("50(nothing)","50","100","250")  # this sets the order
lt <- setNames(c(1,2,3,4),lt.names)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test)+
  geom_line(aes(time,value,linetype=dis))+
  facet_wrap(~id,ncol=2)+theme_bw()+
  ylab("concentration ")+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(151,181),ylim=c(-0.15,0.75))+ labs(linetype="")+
  theme(panel.margin = unit(1, "lines"))+ xlab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(151,181),breaks=seq(151,181,5))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.15,1.75),breaks=seq(-0.15,1.75,0.15))+
  theme(legend.position="top",legend.key =element_blank())+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=lt, breaks=lt.names)
```

[image]

Compare this to the result when you set `lt` as follows:

```
lt <- setNames(c(4,3,2,1),lt.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this overview](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/), you can see which numbers correspond with which linetypes. So if you want to manually assign the default values you would probably have to use: `scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,3,2,5))`

Comment: I don't know why but the figures don't look similar with those values also.