# ggplot with variable line types and colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R with ggplot, I want to create a spaghetti plot (2 quantitative variables) grouped by a third variable to specify line color.  Secondly, I want to aggregate that grouping variable with the line type or width.

Here's an example using the airquality dataset. I want the line's color to represent the month, and the summer months to have a different line width from non-summer months.

First, I created an indicator variable for the aggregated groups:

```
airquality$Summer <- with(airquality, ifelse(Month >= 6 & Month < 9, 1, 0))
```

I would like something like this, but with differing line widths:
[image]

However, this fails:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = airquality, aes(x=Wind, y = Temp, color = as.factor(Month), group = Summer)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = as.factor(Summer))
```

This also fails (specifying `airquality$Summer`):

```
ggplot(data = airquality, aes(x=Wind, y = Temp, 
    color = as.factor(Month), group = airquality$Summer)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = as.factor(airquality$Summer))
```

I attempted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714804/3935558), but get another error:

```
lty <- setNames(c(0, 1), levels(airquality$Summer))

ggplot(data = airquality, aes(x=Wind, y = Temp, 
    color = as.factor(Month), group = airquality$Summer)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = as.factor(airquality$Summer)) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = lty)
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My actual data show very clear trends, and I want to differentiate the top line from all the others below.  My goal is to convince people they should make more than just the minimum payment on their student loans:
[image]

Comment: Try putting `linetype = factor(Summer)` within first `aes`. Still, I can't see the point (can you please explain) of this plot... You should remove points and use `geom_smooth` instead of `geom_line` (as there are multiple days per month).

Comment: IMO if you want to improve your plot - add alpha to lines (they overlap at zero now) and change pallet to sequential (now it's categorical and doesn't look that good with continuous measurements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the group to `Month` and put`linetype` in `aes`:

```
ggplot(data = airquality, aes(x=Wind, y = Temp, color = as.factor(Month), group = Month)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(Summer)))
```

If you want to specify the `linetype` you can use a few methods. Here is one way:

```
lineT <- c("solid", "dotdash")
names(lineT) <- c("1","0")

ggplot(data = airquality, aes(x=Wind, y = Temp, color = as.factor(Month))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(Summer))) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = lineT)
```

Comment: Thanks - this was a simple fix! Can I specify which line gets which type?  Perhaps by ordering the vector Summer, i.e., reverse the 0s and 1s?