# How to rename a (combined) legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to rename a legend which combines different aesthetics in `ggplot2`

For example:

1. Combine color with linetype: [Controlling line color and line type in ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344561/controlling-line-color-and-line-type-in-ggplot-legend)
2. Combine color with shape: [How to recycle colours in a colorbrewer palette using line symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112440/how-to-recycle-colours-in-a-colorbrewer-palette-using-line-symbols)

**How could one rename such a combined legend?** When I try using `name` for `scale_shape_manual` or `scale_color_manual` the combined legend splits into two different legends. That is not what I want.

---

**Possible Solution:** A solution which I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622513/4317408 worked for me...

Basically there are two possible approaches, in both of them for the combined legend to get a new name, the `name` of the two different legends which are combined has to be modified as the same:

```
  scale_color_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(5, "Set1") ) , name = "Combined Legend Title") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,2,3,4,5) , name = "Combined Legend Title")
```

or

```
  guides(shape=guide_legend(title="Combined Legend Title"), color=guide_legend(title="Combined Legend Title"))
```

Still I wonder if there is a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think so. In ggplot, legends combine if their mapping _and_ their name is the same, so AFAIK you'll have to repeat the renaming twice.