# Randomising qualitative colours for large sets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you're mapping qualitatively to colour for a large number of groups, ggplot's automatic colour assignment plots very similar colours adjacently, making it hard to see which refer to which key etc.  To illustrate:

```
require(ggplot2); require(stringr)
df = data.frame(x = letters, y = sample(20:100,26), lab=word("apple ball cat dog elephant frog goat hat ice jackal king lion mango nest owl parrot queen rabbit ship tomato umbrella van watch xylophone yatch zebra", 1:26))
p = ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=lab)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p + scale_fill_discrete()
```

[image]

Its possible to mix up some random colours manually:

```
cols = rainbow(26, s=.6, v=.9)[sample(1:26,26)]
p + scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
```

[image]

.. resulting in more useful breakup of the rainbow, but this seems clumsy, still leaves some colours clumped together and is generally not ideal.  Does ggplot have a native method to achieve something like this (but hopefully better)?

Comment: My advice, don't. It's far too much information in one plot and the colours are not significantly different enough to translate that information usefully for the viewer. Do your best to separate or group the results into meaningful or otherwise functional breaks - your readers will thank you. Notwithstanding the 10% that are colorblind anyways.

Comment: Speaking directly from experience here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616515/recommend-a-scale-colour-for-13-or-more-categories

Comment: Brandon, I appreciate the perceptual issue you raise and normally I'd agree. My issue is I'm dealing with 30+ categories of non-groupable data with quite lengthy titles (too big for x axis), and I want to avoid a 90 degree rotation.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen - I agree with your point. However, sometimes the reader is just - me! - and I want to pick out trends or do preliminary data exploration - something really simple, before dividing the data further into groups. I found this question helpful.

Comment: could you explain the syntax in `rainbow(26, s=.6, v=.9)[sample(1:26,26)]`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Producing a good palette for that many colours is indeed a difficult task. However, there is one solution which may be helpful. Some time ago I forked [this](https://github.com/karthik/ggplot-lecture/) repo and found a reference to [iWantHue](http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/). As far as I can see, the resulting palette is already mixed, so that neighbouring colours look distinguishable.

For instance, for your example I have
[image]

Just in case, the palette is

```
"#89C5DA", "#DA5724", "#74D944", "#CE50CA", "#3F4921", "#C0717C", "#CBD588", "#5F7FC7", 
"#673770", "#D3D93E", "#38333E", "#508578", "#D7C1B1", "#689030", "#AD6F3B", "#CD9BCD", 
"#D14285", "#6DDE88", "#652926", "#7FDCC0", "#C84248", "#8569D5", "#5E738F", "#D1A33D", 
"#8A7C64", "#599861"
```

Comment: Thanks tonyronov this is useful, although I think in essence this variablisation of saturation and value is achievable with a tweek to my code: `col.par = function(n) sample(seq(0.3, 1, length.out=50),n); cols = rainbow(26, s=col.par(26), v=col.par(26))[sample(1:26,26)]`.

Comment: It is. However, when you use `sample`, two or more close-looking colours may fall close to each other randomly. I think the proposed palette is already shuffled properly.

Comment: Fair point. What is the key R code you're referring to? I can see a reference to iWantHue in [ggplot.Rnw](https://github.com/karthik/ggplot-lecture/blob/master/ggplot.Rnw) but  I don't recognise the code format.

Comment: Well, seems iWantHue doest not provide any sort of API, so I just took a JSON from there. BTW, more ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282580/how-to-generate-a-number-of-most-distinctive-colors-in-r).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the presentation is compiled by latex and [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/).

Comment: I like this answer... however I don't appreciate the time I foresee wasting on this website!! ;)

Comment: Note the R version of this - `rwantshue` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71660386/1156245

Answer (score 1):

Should've added this years ago but better late than never.  There's an R port of iwanthue - [rwantshue](https://github.com/hoesler/rwantshue).  Documentation is [here](https://rdrr.io/github/hoesler/rwantshue/).