# How to generate a number of most distinctive colors in R?

Tags: r, colors, palette, color-palette, colorbrewer

I am plotting a categorical dataset and want to use distinctive colors to represent different categories. Given a number `n`, how can I get `n` number of MOST distinctive colors in R? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075140/in-r-how-do-i-change-the-color-value-of-just-one-value-in-ggplot2s-scale-fill-b/6076605#6076605

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563711/r-color-palettes-for-many-data-classes/41230685

Answer (score 177):

I joined all qualitative palettes from `RColorBrewer` package. Qualitative palettes are supposed to provide X most distinctive colours each. Of course, mixing them joins into one palette also similar colours, but that's the best I can get (74 colors).

```
library(RColorBrewer)
n <- 60
qual_col_pals = brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
col_vector = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))
pie(rep(1,n), col=sample(col_vector, n))
```

[image: colour_Brewer_qual_60]

Other solution is: take all R colors from graphical devices and sample from them. I removed shades of grey as they are too similar. This gives 433 colors

```
color = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
```

[image: set of 20 colours]

```
pie(rep(1,n), col=sample(color, n))
```

with 200 colors `n = 200`:

```
pie(rep(1,n), col=sample(color, n))
```

[image: set of 200 colours]

Comment: Is there a possibility to convert the hex codes in `col` to corresponding color names?

Comment: @Prradep which `col` do you mean? the `color` from graphical devices has names. If you mean in general, not all hex code have corresponding color names (there are only 433 colors in `grDevices` but many more hex codes)

Comment: I am mentioning about `col=sample(col_vector, n)` from the `RColorBrewer` package in your code snippet. For example, How to find the color names for    `#B3E2CD, #E78AC3, #B3DE69` available from `sample(col_vector,3)`. Alternatively, How to find all the hex codes given by `brewer.pal` function with their color names.

Comment: @Prradep, as `RColorBrewer` palettes are not derived from `grDevices` colors, that have names mapped, but are just hex codes, to my knowledge, you cannot do this with `RColorBrewer` palettes, even qualitative ones.

Comment: What about when `n` is like 4000?

Comment: @ytu then the colors are not distinguishable. If absolutely necessary, I would suggest looking for "gradient creation" in R and then use randomised sampling of colors. But mapping from colors to factors will not work, human perception can handle maybe 20 - 40 colors, the rest is not that much different.

Answer (score 99):

Here are a few options:

1. Have a look at the `palette` function:

   ```
    palette(rainbow(6))     # six color rainbow
    (palette(gray(seq(0,.9,len = 25)))) #grey scale
   ```
2. And the `colorRampPalette` function:

   ```
    ##Move from blue to red in four colours
    colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))( 4)
   ```
3. Look at the [`RColorBrewer` package](https://rdrr.io/cran/RColorBrewer/) (and [website](http://colorbrewer2.org/)). If you want diverging colours, then select **diverging** on the site. For example,

   ```
    library(RColorBrewer)
    brewer.pal(7, "BrBG")
   ```
4. The [I want hue](https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/) web site gives lots of nice palettes. Again, just select the palette that you need. For example, you can get the rgb colours from the site and make your own palette:

   ```
    palette(c(rgb(170,93,152, maxColorValue=255),
        rgb(103,143,57, maxColorValue=255),
        rgb(196,95,46, maxColorValue=255),
        rgb(79,134,165, maxColorValue=255),
        rgb(205,71,103, maxColorValue=255),
        rgb(203,77,202, maxColorValue=255),
        rgb(115,113,206, maxColorValue=255)))
   ```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It generates colors, but some not very distinctive with each other. maybe I should have emphasized more on that in my questions.

Comment: @RNAer I've updated my answer. You can use suggestions 3 and 4 to get **diverging** palettes.

Comment: `I want hue` is a awesome website. This is exactly what I want. Given a number, how to generate a palette of the number of colors. but can we do it in R automatically?

Comment: It is awesome.  However, there's a lot of machinery behind that web site.  I don't think it will be trivial to re-implement.  It would be nice if `i want hue` had an API that allowed it to be automatically queried (maybe it does -- I didn't spend long looking)

Comment: @BenBolker - I've made a gist for an R version of `i want hue`, [here](https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/45b49da5e260a9fc1cd7). Efficiency could be improved (e.g. by saving colour samples as data objects), but the general idea is there. (Load with `devtools::source_gist('45b49da5e260a9fc1cd7')`)

Comment: (@BenBolker - though the subsetting in HCL space isn't quite right.)

Answer (score 67):

You can also try the [`randomcoloR` package](https://github.com/ronammar/randomcoloR):

```
library(randomcoloR)
n <- 20
palette <- distinctColorPalette(n)
```

You can see that a set of highly distinct colors are chosen when visualizing in a pie chart (as suggested by other answers here):

```
pie(rep(1, n), col=palette)
```

[image]

Shown in a pie chart with 50 colors:

```
n <- 50
palette <- distinctColorPalette(n)
pie(rep(1, n), col=palette)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had to use `unname(distinctColorPalette(n))` to make this work with ggplot. I guess ggplot needs an unnamed vector.

`col_vector <- unname(distinctColorPalette(n))` and then
`... +  scale_color_manual(values=col_vector) ...`

Answer (score 25):

Not an answer to OP's question but it's worth mentioning that there is the [`viridis`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html) package which has good color palettes for sequential data. They are perceptually uniform, colorblind safe and printer-friendly.

To get the palette, simply install the package and use the function `viridis_pal()`. There are four options "A", "B", "C" and "D" to choose

```
install.packages("viridis")
library(viridis)
viridis_pal(option = "D")(n)  # n = number of colors seeked
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is also an excellent talk explaining the complexity of good colormaps on YouTube:

[A Better Default Colormap for Matplotlib | SciPy 2015 | Nathaniel Smith and Stéfan van der Walt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU)

Comment: This is not so suitable for distinctive colours.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `colorRampPalette` from base or `RColorBrewer` package:

With `colorRampPalette`, you can specify colours as follows:

```
colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))(5)
# [1] "#FF0000" "#BF3F00" "#7F7F00" "#3FBF00" "#00FF00"
```

You can alternatively provide hex codes as well:

```
colorRampPalette(c("#3794bf", "#FFFFFF", "#df8640"))(5)
# [1] "#3794BF" "#9BC9DF" "#FFFFFF" "#EFC29F" "#DF8640"
# Note that the mid color is the mid value...
```

With `RColorBrewer` you could use colors from pre-existing palettes:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
brewer.pal(9, "Set1")
# [1] "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" "#FF7F00" "#FFFF33" "#A65628" "#F781BF"
# [9] "#999999"
```

Look at `RColorBrewer` package for other available palettes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I like the last option `brewer.pal`. but it is limited up to 9 colors. I actually have more than 9 categories. The first alternatives generate a gradient colors, which is not as distinctive as I want.

Comment: you won't be able to choose many "distinct" colours. You can get a maximum of 12 I suppose. You should check out http://colorbrewer2.org/ and get the colours (there's 1 12 colour palette if I'm right).

Comment: Looking for more than 12 distinctive colouts will be difficult - I think there's discussion about that on the colorbrewer page

Comment: that's fine, as long as they are the "most" distinctive colors available, even they are becoming less distinctive when number goes up.

Comment: If your issue is similar colours side-by-side when assigned to adjacent categories (as the rainbow palette will do), then you could simply randomize the rainbow output with something like:  
rainbow(n=10)[sample(10)]

Answer (score 13):

I would recomend to use an external source for large color palettes.

http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/

has a service to compose any size of palette according to various parameters and

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/where-can-i-find-a-large-palette-set-of-contrasting-colors-for-coloring-many-d/3815

discusses the generic problem from a graphics designers perspective and gives lots of examples of usable palettes.

To comprise a palette from RGB values you just have to copy the values in a vector as in e.g.:

```
colors37 = c("#466791","#60bf37","#953ada","#4fbe6c","#ce49d3","#a7b43d","#5a51dc","#d49f36","#552095","#507f2d","#db37aa","#84b67c","#a06fda","#df462a","#5b83db","#c76c2d","#4f49a3","#82702d","#dd6bbb","#334c22","#d83979","#55baad","#dc4555","#62aad3","#8c3025","#417d61","#862977","#bba672","#403367","#da8a6d","#a79cd4","#71482c","#c689d0","#6b2940","#d593a7","#895c8b","#bd5975")
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the **Polychrome** package for this purpose. It just requires the number of colors and a few `seedcolors`. For example:

```r
# install.packages("Polychrome")
library(Polychrome)

# create your own color palette based on `seedcolors`
P36 = createPalette(36,  c("#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"))
swatch(P36)
```

[image]

You can learn more about this package at https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v090c01.

Comment: Polychrome looks interesting but doesn't appear to have been updated to be able to use R v4.

Comment: Fixed: download followed by install.packages("scatterplot3d"), 
  install.packages("C:\\...\\Polychrome_1.3.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")

Answer (score 9):

I found a website offering a list of 20 distinctive colours: https://sashat.me/2017/01/11/list-of-20-simple-distinct-colors/

```
col_vector<-c('#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4', '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#fabebe', '#008080', '#e6beff', '#9a6324', '#fffac8', '#800000', '#aaffc3', '#808000', '#ffd8b1', '#000075', '#808080', '#ffffff', '#000000')
```

You can have a try!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about generating `n`  distinctive colors, not a set of defined colors. Try updating your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a set of colors like this:

```r
myCol = c("pink1", "violet", "mediumpurple1", "slateblue1", "purple", "purple3",
          "turquoise2", "skyblue", "steelblue", "blue2", "navyblue",
          "orange", "tomato", "coral2", "palevioletred", "violetred", "red2",
          "springgreen2", "yellowgreen", "palegreen4",
          "wheat2", "tan", "tan2", "tan3", "brown",
          "grey70", "grey50", "grey30")
```

These colors are as distinct as possible. For those similar colors, they form a gradient so that you can easily tell the differences between them.

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding searching distinctive colors is related to search efficiently from an unit cube, where 3 dimensions of the cube are three vectors along red, green and blue axes. This can be simplified to search in a cylinder (HSV analogy), where you fix Saturation (S) and Value (V) and find random Hue values. It works in many cases, and see this here :

https://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/

In R,

```
get_distinct_hues <- function(ncolor,s=0.5,v=0.95,seed=40) {
  golden_ratio_conjugate <- 0.618033988749895
  set.seed(seed)
  h <- runif(1)
  H <- vector("numeric",ncolor)
  for(i in seq_len(ncolor)) {
    h <- (h + golden_ratio_conjugate) %% 1
    H[i] <- h
  }
  hsv(H,s=s,v=v)
}
```

An alternative way, is to use R package "uniformly" 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uniformly/index.html

and this simple function can generate distinctive colors:

```
get_random_distinct_colors <- function(ncolor,seed = 100) {
  require(uniformly)
  set.seed(seed)
  rgb_mat <- runif_in_cube(n=ncolor,d=3,O=rep(0.5,3),r=0.5)
  rgb(r=rgb_mat[,1],g=rgb_mat[,2],b=rgb_mat[,3])
}
```

One can think of a little bit more involved function by grid-search:

```
get_random_grid_colors <- function(ncolor,seed = 100) {
  require(uniformly)
  set.seed(seed)
  ngrid <- ceiling(ncolor^(1/3))
  x <- seq(0,1,length=ngrid+1)[1:ngrid]
  dx <- (x[2] - x[1])/2
  x <- x + dx
  origins <- expand.grid(x,x,x)
  nbox <- nrow(origins) 
  RGB <- vector("numeric",nbox)
  for(i in seq_len(nbox)) {
    rgb <- runif_in_cube(n=1,d=3,O=as.numeric(origins[i,]),r=dx)
    RGB[i] <- rgb(rgb[1,1],rgb[1,2],rgb[1,3])
  }
  index <- sample(seq(1,nbox),ncolor)
  RGB[index]
}
```

check this functions by:

```
ncolor <- 20
barplot(rep(1,ncolor),col=get_distinct_hues(ncolor))          # approach 1
barplot(rep(1,ncolor),col=get_random_distinct_colors(ncolor)) # approach 2
barplot(rep(1,ncolor),col=get_random_grid_colors(ncolor))     # approach 3
```

However, note that, defining a distinct palette with human perceptible colors is not simple. Which of the above approach generates diverse color set is yet to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I have manually found 8 most distinguishable colors as follows,

color = c("blue","red","green3","hotpink3","yellow","maroon1","lightsalmon3","black")

but if you need more, just see here and make your own list:
[http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Etzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf)