# R/Shiny: Unique Colors for Lines in Plotly

Tags: r, charts, shiny, plotly

I'm attempting to have Plotly choose unique colors for all lines that are being created on a chart. Currently, there are 5 lines, but in the future there could be more or less. I thought something like `line = ~list(color = c("red", "purple")),` would work, but I can't get even two lines to be different colors in the chart.

Code:

```
fig <- plot_ly(theDataframe, x = ~start_date, y = ~score, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
                   marker = ~list(color="purple"),
                   line = ~list(color = c("red", "purple")),
                   source="master_results",
                   hoverinfo = 'text',
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using discrete colors with colorscale as [described here](https://plotly.com/r/discrete-color/), using a qualitative color sequence (see a list [here](https://plotly.com/r/builtin-colorscales/)).

`line =list(colorscale = 'Accent')`

If you need more colors than the ones available in the built-in palettes, see [this QA to generate a custom color palette with a large number of distinctive colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282580/how-to-generate-a-number-of-most-distinctive-colors-in-r).