# many different colors in r

Tags: r, plot, colors

I am to make a plot with 200 different colors corresponding to 200 individulas. I want the colors to be as different as possible, because I want to be able to distinguish between the individuals.

I have tried using

```
col = alpha(topo.colors(200)[i],0.3)
col = alpha(rainbow(200)[i],0.3)
col = alpha(i,0.3)
```

where i corresponds to the individuals in a loop. topo.color and rainbow uses different colors, but they are very alike, so it is not possible to see the differences.

Comment: It is impossible to make a graph with 200 colors that are so different that the human eye can grasp it. I strongly advise to find a different approach, e.g. split your graph or group your individuals.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6076605/3710546