# Setting legend colours for stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, colors, legend

I have a stacked bar chart (3 columns with each column have multiple stacks, say 20). Though there can be say 20 stacks, only 3 dominate (accounting for over 90% of the total).
I wish to designate specific colours for the 3 dominants (say "Good" blue, "Average" green, "Bad" red), with the other stacks being whatever the default colours are.
Using ggplot, how do you assign this? I get an error message:
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 17 needed but only 3 provided.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide some examples on the code you were using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 : Color One Category Separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521580/ggplot2-color-one-category-separately)

Comment: Hi - my apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I don't know how to send you the data! You have two transport categories: car/bus, and you have multiple countries (>15) though you wish to highlight 3 countries clearly in the chart. The code is: vehicle<-read.csv("test.csv")
Table_Car<-vehicle %>%
  select(Transport, Country, Amount ) %>%
  group_by(Transport, Country) %>%
  summarise(Amount=sum(Amount))
Chart_Vehicle<-ggplot(data = Table_Car, aes(x=Transport, y=Amount, fill=Country)) + 
  geom_col() +

labs(title="Transport amounts by country", y="sterling", x=NULL)