# Create specific vector of colors

Tags: r, plot, colors

How to create a vector of colors where one certain output receives a different color than the others?

Manually it can be done like in the following example:

```
pts.7 <- cbind(1:7, 1:7)
mycols <- c("black","black","black","red","black","black","black")
plot(pts.7, col=mycols)
```

However for bigger data set like the following it doesn't work:

```
pts.400 <- cbind(runif(400), runif(400))
df <- data.frame(a = 1:400)
pts.400.df <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts.400, df)
```

How could a vector of colors be build that all points plotted get a grayscale color except `point$a==158` which should be plotted red?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 : Color One Category Separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521580/ggplot2-color-one-category-separately)

Comment: You can also do it manually using `mycols <- rep("black", 400); mycols[158] <- "red"`

Comment: @A.Suliman, no this is not a ggplot question.

Comment: @Axeman you are correct but it's a color related question. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette) there is an answer to `ggplot2` and `base R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick is to use logical indexing:

```
plot(pts.400.df, col = c('black', 'red')[(pts.400.df$a == 158) + 1])
```

Each `FALSE` will be black, each `TRUE` will be red.